# how to make plot invisible on axes of MATLAB GUI

Tags: plot, matlab-guide, axes

I have designed MATLAB GUI in which there are two axes for displaying images. Now, keeping image as background, i am plotting some points(or plot) on axes as foreground. I want to make the plot invisible(which is displayed as foreground over an image) dynamically through code. Please help me out. I tried with set(gcf,'visible','off'), but it makes the whole GUI invisible. Also, I tried set(gca,'visible','off'), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
p = plot(something);
```

You can then make it invisible using

```
set(p,'visible','off');
```

or make it visible again using

```
  set(p,'visible','on');
```

By the way, the plot can be done on the same axes.